# Why do oranges in the US have a small separate part?

Tags: botany, fruit, agriculture

Why do oranges in the US have a small separate detachable part at the tip which is separate from the other pods? It looks like a tiny orange itself and has a long fiber attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specific to navel oranges, which have a conjoined twin fruit.

This [blog](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=103250589) gives an account of this.